# Is there a way to merge two MatPlotLib plots together?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, graph

I have been trying to merge these two plots together but have not found a built-in in the documentation for MatPlotLib on how to do so. I want to show the two bar values next to each and for every new entry, add the new entry to the graph while shifting the other entries over to make space. The plots are below.

[image: Plot #1]
[image: Plot #2]

As stated prior, when I say merge, I do not simply mean just plop Plot A onto Plot B, but rather join the plots together so both bar values are shown in the same graph, like this:

[image]

The reasoning for this is that I will be able to log all the entries in a single plot without having to manually do so. By implementing something like this in my code, it would make entries go a lot quicker.

**EDIT**: I understand that I can graph these two together, but that is not what I am looking for. Once I get the necessary input, my program creates a graph of that data and saves it as a file. I am looking to *append* any new data to that original file by just shifting the original value over to the left in order to make space.

**EDIT 2**: How could I extract the data from each plot and after doing so, create a new graph? This would seem to be another acceptable workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything preventing you from plotting each of them side by side but changing the index?

```
a, b, c = 2, 5, 3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
count = 0
ax.bar(count, a)
# if prgoram produces a new output then...
count += 1
ax.bar(count, b)  # index means new bar plot has shifted
# again
count += 1
ax.bar(count, c)  # shifted again
```

This should automatically expand the x-axis anyway. You may have to alter this slightly if you've particularly concenred about the width of these bars.

If this isn't what you wanted you could consider replotting with the bar container or even just stripping the height to reuse.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
count = 0
bar_cont = ax.bar(count, a)  # reference to the bar container of interest
print(bar_cont.get_height())
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
people = ['JOHN DOE', 'BOB SMITH']
values = [14,14]
ax.bar(people,values)
plt.show()
```

Should be the solution. You just have to pass a list instead of a single value to the plt.bar() function. More detailed explaination [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/matplotlib/matplotlib_bar_plot.htm).

Comment: I currently have the first plot and the second separate, but I'm looking to combine them as well as have them dynamically move whenever I add a new new plot.

Comment: Well as far as know you cannot combine two drawn plots without their data, you may only plot them sidebyside. If your program can return the data instead of plotting a graph with it, you can combine new data and draw the desired bar plot with the code above. So basically you need to combine the data in order to draw a combined bar plot.